# Unknown error wont open from computer. Basic

Tags: vb.net

[image]

```
Sub ShowFileContents(ByVal strFileName As String)
    Dim fs As New FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim TextFile As New StreamReader(fs)

    Me.txtFileContents.Text = Nothing

    Dim strLineOfText As String
    Do While TextFile.Peek > -1
        strLineOfText = TextFile.ReadLine()

        Me.txtFileContents.Text = Me.txtFileContents.Text & strLineOfText & vbCrLf
    Loop
    TextFile.Close()
    fs.Close()
End Sub
```

Why cant I open a file when I run program all it says is "Save" or "Cancel"

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot?

Comment: It looks like you could shorten that to `txtFileContents.Text = File.ReadAllText(strFileName)`.

Comment: Sure @Neolisk there it is

Comment: I can hardly see anything on it. Please remove irrelevant areas. Paint should help you a lot.

Comment: In Windows 7, you can press the Windows key and then type `snip`; it should highlight "Snipping Tool". Press Enter to run it, and choose the area to grab. Save as a .png file to preserve the clarity.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I've always used Paint, even after upgrading to Windows 7. You can assign to CTRL+ALT+P to launch it, and then use ALT+PrintScreen, to minimize the amount of work needed.

Comment: Regarding the code above, when you see something like this `Me.txtFileContents.Text = Me.txtFileContents.Text &` in a loop, it should immediately raise a red flag to use a StringBuilder. In this case, however @AndrewMorton suggested an even better solution to replace the whole block.

Comment: sorry @Neolisk I put a better pic

Comment: You don't need to show a screenshot to really show code, just paste it here as code. I was asking for a screenshot to explain this phrase `when I run program all it says is "Save" or "Cancel"`, and particularly what `says` means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why cant I open a file when I run program all it says is "Save" or "Cancel" What Im trying to do is open a file from my documents and display it in the textbox below. I have the save file working but not the open file

It looks like you could benefit from using the OpenFileDialog control rather than a textbox to get the file path you want to open.

Here's an example:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim ofp As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofp.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ShowFileContents(ofp.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
Sub ShowFileContents(ByVal strFileName As String)
    Dim TextFile As New StreamReader(strFileName)
    txtFileContents.Text = Nothing
    Do While Not TextFile.EndOfStream
        txtFileContents.AppendText(TextFile.ReadLine() & vbCrLf)
    Loop
    TextFile.Close()
End Sub
```